# How to get the selected rows of smartTable in UI5

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to select all recods that user checked, but I can't.
Using the code:

```
var gettingInternalTable = this.byId("bpTable").getTable(),
    gettingAllRows = gettingInternalTable.getRows();
```

I can get all the rows that have been showing in my screen, but I can't filter then by the checkbox.
I'm using the smartTable to show the data.

Follow it's my link:
[image: My print screen]

This is my View:

```
<mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:smartTable="sap.ui.comp.smarttable"
    controllerName="opensap.odataBasic.controller.App" height="100%">
    <Page title="{i18n>appTitle}">
        <content>
            <smartTable:SmartTable id="bpTable" header="{i18n>UList}" editable="false" 
                                                   showRowCount="true" enableAutoBinding="true"
                showFullScreenButton="true" tableType="Table">
                <smartTable:layoutData>
                    <FlexItemData growFactor="1" baseSize="0%"/>
                </smartTable:layoutData>
                <smartTable:customToolbar>
                    <OverflowToolbar width="100%" id="toolbar2">
                        <content>
                            <Button xmlns="sap.m" text="Button" id="button" 
                                                                  press=".reprocessSelectedRecords"/>
                        </content>
                    </OverflowToolbar>
                </smartTable:customToolbar>
            </smartTable:SmartTable>
        </content>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

This is my controller:

```
onInit: function () {
            this.getView().addStyleClass("sapUiSizeCompact"); 
            var oConfig = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("config");
            var userName = oConfig.getProperty("/UserName");
            var bpModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("bpModel");
            var oTable = this.getView().byId("bpTable");

            //To-Do Bind Model to table
            oTable.setModel(bpModel);
            oTable.setEntitySet("OZPSTA_MON_ERROR");
            oTable.setInitiallyVisibleFields("id", "codigo_atena", "hora", "data", "flag", 
                                                   "tableName", "field", "erro", "operacao");
        },
        reprocessSelectedRecords: function (oEvent) {

            var gettingInternalTable = this.byId("bpTable").getTable(),
                gettingAllRows = gettingInternalTable.getRows();

            gettingAllRows.map(function (item) {
                // get the selected rows
            });

        }
```

Comment: IMHO you dont need to access the table, the information should already be available in your model thanks to double way binding. (I never used SmartTable though so I might be wrong)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to get the selected rows in the following way-

```
var gettingInternalTable = this.byId("bpTable").getTable(),
                gettingAllRows = gettingInternalTable.getRows();
                oSelIndices = gettingInternalTable.getSelectedIndices();
//oSelIndices will have index of the rows
for(var i of oSelIndices){
console.log(gettingAllRows[i].getBindingContext().getObject())
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to be of help. You can accept it if you find it answers your question.